# PostgreSQL Unique Index Error

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, backup, unique

I'm busy writing a script to restore a database backup and I've run into something strange.

I have a table.sql file which only contains create table structures like

```
create table ugroups
  (
    ug_code char(10) not null ,
    ug_desc char(60) not null
  );
```

I have a second data.csv file which only contains delimiter data such as

```
xyz | dummy data
abc | more nothing
fun | is what this is
```

Then I have a third index.sql file which only creates indexes as such

```
create unique index i_ugroups on ugroups
  (ug_code);
```

I use the commands from the terminal like so

```
/opt/postgresql/bin/psql -d dbname -c "\i /tmp/table.sql"   # loads table.sql
```

I have a batch script that loads in the data which works perfectly. Then I use the command

```
/opt/postgresql/bin/psql -d dbname -c "\i /tmp/index.sql"   # loads index.sql
```

When I try to create the unique indexes it is giving me the error

```
ERROR:  could not create unique index "i_ugroups"
DETAIL:  Key (ug_code)=(transfers ) is duplicated.
```

What's strange is that when I execute the table.sql file and the index.sql file together and load the data last I get no errors and it all works.

Is there something I am missing? why would it not let me create the unique indexes after the data has been loaded?

Comment: maybe you accidentally loaded data twice before creating index?

Answer (score 0):

There are two rows in your column `ug_code` with the data "transfers " and that's why it can't create the index.

Why it would succeed if you create the index first, I don't know. But I would suspect that the second time it tries to insert "transfers " into database, it just fails the `insert` that time and other data gets inserted succesfully.